# A quit command weaker than windowkill?

Tags: command-line, x11, kill, window, xdotool

Typing in `xdotool getwindowfocus windowkill` currently terminates the active window and bypasses any safeguards like "would you like to save your work?".  Is there a weaker command than `windowkill` I can here use that won't make such bypasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soft way to request an X11 application to close its window and possibly then exit is to send it a [`WM_DELETE_WINDOW`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#s-4.2.8.1) message.

Xdotool doesn't appear to have a way to do this. You can do it in Perl with [X11::Protocol::WM](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?X11%3A%3AProtocol%3A%3AWM). Untested:

```
perl -MX11::Protocol -MX11::Protocol::WM -e '$X = X11::Protocol::new(); X11::Protocol::WM::set_wm_protocol($X, ($X->GetInputFocus())[0], "WM_DELETE_WINDOW")'
```

Alternatively, [`wmctrl`](https://sites.google.com/site/tstyblo/wmctrl/) can do that:

```
wmctrl -c :ACTIVE:
```